# Старое или новое оформление Русского SO

Tags: обсуждение, обновление

Извините, даже не вопрос. Прошу вас проголосовать за старое или новое оформление Русского сообщества **Stack Overflow**. Голосование будет в ответах из 3 вариантов нажмите треугольник вверх за выбранный вариант. Еще раз извините, **просто для личного интереса**.

Comment: Промежуточные варианты с лучшим от обеих миров не рассматриваются?

Comment: Хотите голосований, создайте ответы соответствующие.

Comment: Спасибо, @alexout лично я голосую за новый. Мы не стоим на месте.

Comment: @Arhad пункт "Неплохо но может лучше"

Comment: **Предупреждение.** Обсуждаемое тут "новое" оформление недавно стало старым. Смотрите на дату вопроса прежде чем участвовать в обсуждении.

Comment: Более новый дизайн обсуждается тут: [Новый адаптивный дизайн на подходе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/178779)

Answer (score 3):

Неплохо, но можно и лучше (перечисляем ниже):

- Нет кнопки справки.
- Цветовая гамма не радует.
- Переход между сайтами должен быть слева, а не справа.

Comment: Справка есть, там где значок вопросика.

Comment: Но я бы слегка затемнил шапку на цвет #f4f4f4

Comment: @Duoxx а я себе сделал )) https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0xY.jpg

Comment: Я тоже. А как сохранить цвет в кеше чтобы заново не ставить?

Comment: @Duoxx расширение в браузере Stylish - и делай все что хочешь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ? Реклама казино не режется даже AdBlock.

Comment: @Aid там фото, а не реклама казино

Comment: У меня реклама выскочила.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скинь CSS.

Comment: @Alex78191 http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37836008#37836008

Comment: Кнопка справки есть у новичков.

Answer (score 2):

Ненавижу прилепленные панели на сайтах. Занимают место на мониторе, которого вечно не хватает. Хочу, чтобы панель прокручивалась вверх.

Comment: [Это можно выключить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/).

Comment: @D-side, да, я уже нашёл настройку. Снова радуюсь жизни :). К сожалению, на многих сайтах прилепленные панели сильно мешают.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая шапка, оставить и радоваться.

Comment: А вот это так и будет!

Comment: Комментарии - в чат, тут только голосовалка.

Comment: Я уменьшил высоту шапки [сравнение](https://i.imgur.com/lFcqEw4.png)  https://pastebin.com/vbamsXxp Так при масштабе 110% комфортнее

Answer (score -1):

Плохо, собираем петицию на откат до старой панельки.

Comment: Этого не будет.

Comment: @alexolut, да что Вы говорите? Большой перевес против всё же может помочь. Да это просто пункт голосовалки.

Comment: Такие идеи надо продвигать на родной версии SO, а не на локализованной, коей является русская.

Comment: @alexolut, что мешает локально поменять?

Comment: как у Шиманского со своими скриптами что ли?

Comment: @alexolut, как вариант. Но имелось ввиду правка разработчиками нашего уголка сети. Запилить отдельную плашку, с правками и пожеланиями.

Comment: обособленный мирок никто пилить с точки зрения дизайна не станет. Максимум можем рассчитываться на свои цвета. Вряд ли тут даже будут собственные медальки как на некоторых сайтах. Всё-таки между SO разных языков должно быть какое-то единообразие.

Comment: @alexolut, создавать новый интерфейс для нас не будут. Скорее всего, хотя... Но откатить до старой-то можно.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю убрать неуместную толстую линию над панелью меню:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... и поместить её **под** панелью:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Обратите внимание, как органично она сочетается с нижележащей тенью, даже если панель прикреплена.

Во-первых, избавимся от визуального мусора и бессмысленно занятого пространства высотой в несколько пикселей.

Во-вторых, визуально отделим светлую панель от остальной части страницы со схожим цветом фона.

Comment: И та есть затемнении, которое отделяет от страницы.

Comment: @Alex78191, затемнения (которое я назвал «тенью») недостаточно, оно малозаметное.

Answer (score -1):

Новый дизайн классный! То есть поддерживаю. Но.. эх лучше б адаптивность добавили (при уменьшении и увеличении окна браузера).