# Новый адаптивный дизайн на подходе

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, дизайн, адаптивный-дизайн

Если верить [Responsive design coming to all Beta & Undesigned sites soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/260198), то за месяц после выкатки на [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/new-stock-theme-roll-out) нового дизайна команда SE собрала полезный фидбек.

В скором времени нас ждёт та же участь, вероятно, завтра, 21 Сентября. Следить за прогрессом можно по [этому треду](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/260198). Правда, на счёт нас я не уверен, т.к:

1. > you'll know that one of the staff will usually post a discussion on
   >   each meta site as the theme rolls out

   Но я не нашёл у нас ни одного поста касательно адаптивного дизайна от сотрудников.
2. Про новый дизайн @alexolut спрашивал их много недель назад. Тогда они [ответили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314345/unable-to-upload-an-image-or-even-close-upload-popup-when-responsive-design-is-o/314421#comment1030490_314421), что выкатят в течении недели, но что-то не получилось. Возможно, завтра мы опять не увидим нового дизайна.

Команда SE ожидает, что багов не будет (¬‿¬ ), но если, всё же, вы наткнётесь на косяки в новой теме после выкатки, то либо напишите про них в оригинальном посте, или в этом, тогда я(или кто-то другой) опубликую это на MSE.

Если у вас претензии к навигации новой, то используйте [существующее MSE обсуждение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/260198).

Некоторые уточнения:

- Левая менюшка активна почти на всех страницах (но может быть свёрнута в меню в настройках профиля - [инструкция](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16736)).
- Активная адаптивная вёртска, позволяющая сайту корректировать дизайн в зависимости от ширины браузера без прокрутки страниц (некоторые страницы еще не обновлены). Пока, если вы предпочитаете прокрутку, вы можете отключить эта фичу, щелкнув ссылку «отключить адаптивность» в футере.
- Подчёркивание ссылок для наглядности.

Связанные треды:

- [Disable Responsiveness](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7821/15479).
- [What is the “Responsiveness”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311366/260198)
- [Unable to upload an image or even close upload popup when responsive design is on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314345/unable-to-upload-an-image-or-even-close-upload-popup-when-responsive-design-is-o/314421#comment1030490_314421).

**UPD:** получил [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?noredirect=1#comment1034551_310908) о том, что у нас выкатят в ближайшую неделю.

**UPD2:** [завтра вечером](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?noredirect=1#comment1035044_310908).

**UPD3:** обо всех проблемах/багах нового дизайна пишите на MSE: [Responsive design for international sites will be released soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315856/260198).
Или можете опубликовать ответом в этом вопросе, кто-нибудь переведёт и перенесёт на MSE.

Comment: У нас на мете писать никто не будет: «...you'll know that one of the staff will **usually** post a discussion on each meta site as the theme rolls out. With so many sites using this theme, **we decided it'd be easier to post one announcement here on MSE** and feature it so that the entire network can see it....»

Comment: @defaultlocale SOru не англоязычный. На локализованных сайтах они должны это делать.

Comment: Должны, и может даже напишут. Но из поста на большой мете это никак не следует.  В предыдущем комменте мне надо было бы написать «не собирается» вместо «не будет».

Comment: Единственное, чего хотелось бы получить от нового адаптивного дизайна - это возможность видеть результат редактируемого примера кода на мобиле, или на худой конец не убирать возможность вернуться в мобиле в полную версию, чтобы воспользоваться этой функцией.

Comment: О, завезли. И сразу же вопрос: почему на мете есть вертикальная полоска с правого края страницы, а на основном сайте нету?

Comment: @andreymal не знаю. На SOen также. Но лучше это в виду ответов оформлять.

Comment: @andreymal всё норм, спросил у сотрудников. Это by-design. Но за внимание спасибо)

Comment: @Suvitruf или что-то изменили, или я просто сел за другой монитор и сейчас заметил, что фон на мете не белый, а слегка серый, тогда полоска не лишняя)

Answer (score 3):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

> **От активного юзера:** выкатили вариант перевода: **Отменить**

---

При попытке задать вопрос не переведена кнопка **Discard**.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В трансе строка с ключом: `d94b42030b9785fd754d5c1754961269`.

Comment: @suvitruf прикольно, можно ставить красные метки без ромба :)

Comment: @alexolut в сообщении то да)

Answer (score 2):

[статус-отложено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)

> **От разработчиков:** Когда выкатят [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer), это пофиксит проблему во всех браузерах независимо от размера экрана путём добавления выпадающего меню:
>
> [image: Preview of how custom question lists will hide overflowing tabs]

---

Один элемент налазит на другой элемент:

[image: SO]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315973/260198

Comment: @Suvitruf как рассказать участникам, что они могут включить несколько бета-фич на https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/ ? Сайт станет намного лучше(имхо). Может, добавить в вопрос или написать ответ(хотя ответы вроде для багов)?

Comment: Вы про "Beta test new themes"? Это опция не связана с адаптивным дизайном. Про возможность отключения левого меню добавлю в вопрос чуть позже текст.

Comment: @Suvitruf еще там Custom Questions List можно включить(Opt me in)

Comment: @Suvitruf слово "Сводка" почему то стало с маленькой буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Один из ответов здесь выглядит очень "интересно" на моем Android телефоне:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

> **От активного юзера:** перевели.

---

На странице настроек нет перевода блока про левую панель: [На странице настроек нет перевода текста по поводу левой панели](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7979/15479)

Answer (score 1):

[дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)[локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

[Текст описания выборки занимает 5 строк из-за длинных кнопок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7986/15479) на странице [не отвеченных вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags).

Comment: Две метки в приложении под Android [выглядят как одна](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t5Tb.png). Хорошая такая метка :)

Comment: @alexolut на мобиле вообще много косяков видел. Не знаю, репорить ли это всё или нет.

Comment: в приложении или в браузере? Приложение заморожено, так что репортить можно, но особо без смысла. Если в браузере, то стоит обязательно репортить.

Comment: @alexolut в браузере на старом айфоне. Там экран мелкий.

Comment: про мелкий экран могут зарезать из-за размеров. Надо уточнить у SE какие минимальные размеры они вообще поддерживать собираются.