# Разные значения изменения репутации в верхней панели и на вкладке репутации профиля

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено, репутация, уведомления

На основном сайте, в вашем акк на вкладке репутация можно увидеть сколько прирост твоей репутации. И можно посмотреть прирост на полосе вверху страницы, там где размещен кубок. И вот так получается что у меня прирост на вкладке 16 баллов а на кубке 2. Либо я не понимаю что-то, либо ошибка какая-то.

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]

Comment: Подтверждаю, "кубок" багнулся. У меня +10 в профиле, которое на "кубке" никак не отразилось.

Comment: фух))) я думал что у меня уже глюки)))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko пофиксили.

Comment: да уже полетели балы)) спасибо, вы все молодцы

Comment: Опять забажилось: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315892/260198

Comment: что-то ему нездоровится ))) а что идет не так? глюк какой-то может просто?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko возможно связано с выкаткой нового дизайна. Что-то ломают по ходу дела)

Comment: а где новый дизайн? типа здесь на ruSO? потому-что я пару мелких деталей заметил и все, или они постепенно внедряют?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/15479 на многих сайтах выкатывают, скоро и у нас будет. Возможно эти что-то сломали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На MSE тоже обсуждается: [Reputation changes not visible in the achievement box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315836/260198).

Проблема с уведомлениями в кубке, насколько я могу судить.

**UPD:** [пофиксили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315841/260198):

> A new type of error we hadn't seen before propagating chat moderator
>   events got jammed up in the queue after a race with an account merge.
>   A fix by Marc Gravell has been built out and we're watching the
>   aggregator queue drain now.
>
> All should be back to normal in about 10-20 minutes.

**UPD2:** [этот же баг опять появился](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315892/260198).

Comment: ок я понял, просто думаю напишу, вдруг ошибка какая-то :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko всё правильно. Лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть)

Answer (score 2):

Значение на "кубке" отсчитывается с момента последнего нажатия на "кубок", а значение на вкладке - с момента последнего посещения вкладки.

Поскольку обычно вы раскрываете "кубок" значительно чаще чем открываете вкладку в профиле - расхождение в их показаниях является нормальным.

---

Еще отличия:

1. "Кубок" суммирует изменения репутации по всем сайтам сети SE, в то время как в профиле показывается только текущий сайт.
2. Хоть "кубок" и учитывает все события - активируется он только при "крупных". Там, похоже, намеренно не показывают всякий мусор вроде "-2 репутации из-за голоса против".

Comment: Судя по обсуждению на MSE, там реально бага какая-то.

Answer (score 1):

*Дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7952/208074) участника Pavel Mayorov*.

Похоже, дело было так:

1. Вы получили 14 баллов. Кубок показывает 14, вкладка показывает 14.
2. Вы раскрыли «кубок». Счётчик на кубке обнулился, но на вкладке осталось старое значение.
3. Вы получили ещё два балла. Кубок показывает 2 (полученные только что), вкладка показывает 16 (14 старых + 2 новых).
4. Вы открыли страницу профиля и увидели цифру 16.
5. теперь, если вы перейдёте на вкладку, счётчик на ней также обнулится.

Comment: @Archad, может быть вы и правы, просто мне кажется что все должно быть синхронно.

Comment: Разработчики сайта так не считают. Кстати, такая же ситуация и с «лотком» рядом с кубком — его счётчик сбрасывается отдельно от вкладки  «Реакции».

Comment: возможно мне кажется, но раньше все было нормально, но я могу ошибаться

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko нет, так было всегда.