# На странице настроек нет перевода текста по поводу левой панели

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, адаптивный-дизайн, настройки-профиля

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст:

> When you check this box, the left navigation will no longer be pinned
>   to the left of the page on Q&A sites.

В трансе строка с ключом `372633297bdb617f09bf8e4516f567e9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант перевода:

> Если вы выберете эту опцию, левая навигационная панель больше не будет
>   закреплена на страницах сайтов сети.

Там в придаточном предложении **left** повторяется. Не думаю, что стоит повторно это слово переводить, т.к. в первой части предложения уже говорится, что это **левая панель**. Логично, что она не будет закреплена слева)

Comment: Всех сайтов илиэтого?

Comment: @Qwertiy всех. Думаете, стоит это уточнение в перевод добавить? В оригинале я тоже не вижу слова **all**.

Comment: Нет, я просто спросил. Уже проверил - всех сайтов, к тому же без неё только хуже становится. Брррррр...