# Текст описания выборки занимает 5 строк из-за длинных кнопок

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, адаптивный-дизайн

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обсуждение на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315978/260198

Поступило предложение ужать текст перевода.

К примеру, **С Отслеживаемыми метками** можно ужать до **мои метки**, как и на SOen (там на кнопке **My Tags**).

Тогда будет 3 строки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может, просто `display: flex` снести? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFNYG.png

Comment: @Qwertiy они не хотят трогать css. Я это предлагал на MSE.

Comment: я б еще "Без единого ответа" поменял на "Без ответов"

Comment: да и стиль этот "каждое слово с заглавной" как то сомнителен

Comment: @teran этот стиль очень много где используется, к сожалению )=

Comment: еще можно сократить ".... или с ответами без голосов"

Comment: вообще кстати, в оригинале upvoted, а у нас просто голоса, не уточняя за или против (:

Comment: По поводу заглавных букв отписался: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315979/260198

Comment: К проблеме можно подойти с двух сторон. (1) Уменьшить длину строк сортировок (замечания от @teran выше) «без ответа», «все» или «вопрос». Попробовать уменьшить надпись, идущую за счетчиком. (2) Подправить стили. Мне кажется, стоит двигаться сразу во всех направлениях.

Answer (score 7):

Предлагаю просто убрать из стилей `display: flex` и получится одна строка на пояснение и одна строка на вкладки. По-моему, красиво:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Кастомными стилями? Разработчики, судя по их ответам, не горят желанием в вёрстке что-либо менять.

Comment: Значит надо больше людей, которые их убедят.

Comment: Вся эта тема висит на Николасе. Он должен курировать все эти репорты и т.п.

Comment: @Suvitruf, считаешь, что число голосов не зачтётся разработчиками?

Comment: Станут ли они менять вещи, которые потенциально могут сломать **большую** часть сайтов сети ради пары интернациональных? Ну, голосуем, посмотрим. Просто, то, что они сделали, опять же, говорит о том, что они при разработке всё ещё не учитывают интернациональные сайты. Грустно, на самом деле.

Comment: Ну а как они их учтут?

Comment: Проверять не только с английским текстом?

Comment: @Suvitruf, так переводы же появляются уже после релиза - где заранее взять текст?

Comment: Судя по тому, что я вижу, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315979/260198, это никак не связано с отсутствием перевода. Они просто не задумались, что где-то правила не такие как у них)

Comment: Давно пора локализацию css делать. Вот до арабов доберутся и что-нибудь придумают.

Comment: А для желающих решать проблему через юзерстили я бы посоветовал `.grid { flex-wrap: wrap; }`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, как-то сомнительная идея все гриды портить. Я б предложил `#mainbar .grid:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}`.

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы сформулировал это не как "все гриды портить", а как "все гриды чинить" :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тут весь сайт на гридах - мало ли что перенесётся из того, что не должно.

Comment: @Qwertiy хуже точно не будет. Потому что альтернатива переносу - либо ужатие в размерах как обсуждаемое тут, либо пропадание из области видимости. Оба варианты уродские.

Comment: Так, лол, до меня дошло почему у меня все красиво отображается. Я же себе правый сайдбар выключил :-)