# Отмена написания ответа не переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы, ответы

Вместо кнопки отмена выводится "Discard".

> [image: Скриншот дефекта локализации]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7991/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утвердил предложенный перевод на Transifex.

> Отменить

Будет на сайте после прохода по всем технологическим инстанциям.

Comment: Выкатили вместе с другими правками.