# Съехала разметка

Tags: дефект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При просмотре вопросов с меткой, если присутствует колонка "Конкурсные", строка заезжает на соседний блок.

Comment: Об этом дефекте, оказывается, уже писали в теме [Новый адаптивный дизайн на подходе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/184217).