# Заголовки тревог "залезают" на навигационное окно

Tags: дефект, дизайн, тревоги, профиль-участника, история-тревог

На странице тревог возникает проблема с размерами блоков с заголовками на небольших разрешениях:

> [image: Картинка тревоги 1]

---

> [image: Картинка тревоги 2]

Проблема есть как и на [SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), так и на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com). На др. сайтах не могу проверить, но не исключаю, что там такая же проблема.

Comment: На сайте не очень с адаптивностью. Тут вообще весь сайт кошмарит на некоторых страницах.

Comment: @byVerng а ведь совсем недавно выкатили адаптивный дизайн https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/15479 (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf разницы не заметил) Всё также не удобно пользоваться.... Я вообще чёт не пойму: вроде сайт на флексах, в чём проблема адаптировать.

Comment: @byVerng не в приоритете. Насколько я знаю, большая часть ресурсов сейчас тратится на разработку https://stackoverflow.com/teams

Comment: @byVerng Согласен на счёт адаптации. Некоторые страницы совсем не адаптируются и приходиться их скролить по горизонтали, хотя вполне можно все блоки уместить в рамках разрешения, если не давать им `width` в `px`.

Comment: [Известная тема](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379814/3240681)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не спешат судя по всему фиксить, раз первый раз упоминается о воспроизведении проблемы аж с 11 декабря прошлого года.