# Не дови на меня

Tags: дефект, выборы, адаптивный-дизайн

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3

> [image: баг]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGCkC.jpg

Comment: Это ж мобильная версия? Если так, то нет смысла репортить. Эта версия - один большой баг, ей вряд ли кто-то будет заниматься =/

Comment: @Suvitruf в том и дело, что не мобильная, а полная адаптивная

Comment: Зато есть что полистать))

Comment: @andreymal тогда добавьте лучше в пост инфу про ОС, браузер, версию и т.п. А лучше сразу на MSE опубликовать вопрос (:

Comment: @Suvitruf любая, любой, любая :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVDAu.png

Comment: @andreymal 

Comment: https://is.gd/knBPaO 

Еще вот так в Опере(не у меня). Говорят, это баг 100% масштаба, после Ctrl+/- все возвращается в нормальный вид.

Comment: [Известная ситуация](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8005/176217). Пока что решается исключительно уменьшением длины перевода. То же на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316187/339911).