# Почему в мобильной версии сайта не видно количество просмотров?

Tags: обсуждение, мобильная-версия

Часто бывает — хочу посмотреть результаты моего вопроса по-быстрому, то есть ответили на вопрос, оставили комментарий, или же сколько людей видели. Тогда смотрю через телефон, а там не видно количество просмотров.
Кто-то скажет: "А зачем тебе количество просмотров?". Чтобы знать, что делать дальше. Если вопрос видели 5 человек, то буду ждать, а если уже 100 просмотров и пустота, то объявлю конкурс.

---

Что с этим делать?

Comment: А мне кажется, нужно делать ровно наоборот: если вопрос уже видели целых 100 человек и не ответили, значит они не знают ответа и не смогут помочь даже с конкурсом, а если всего 5 человек, то стоит привлечь побольше просмотров с помощью конкурса

Comment: А в [адаптивном дизайне](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7907) просмотры всё-таки видны: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGYp6.png

Comment: @andreymal Возможно видели и знают ответ но не хотят вмешаться потому что это займёт много времени, а +50, 100, ... балов к репутации может мотивировать их.

Comment: @andreymal а как включить такой дизайн?

Comment: Сперва перейти на полную версию сайта, и на нём внизу будет ссылочка «Включить адаптивный дизайн»

Comment: Лень было верстать ее)

Comment: @LeopardLGD <offtop> not 'ask for questions' but 'ask questions' (your bio)</offtop>

Comment: Что? @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica

Comment: Ну у вас в "о себе" написано :<q>I ask for many questions here</q> .А правильно будет: I ask many questions here.

Comment: @LeopardLGD (см выше)

Comment: Не страшно, пусть будет